# Selecting transactions using date

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm trying to select transactions for the past ten days using

```
where transaction.date > date(now() - interval '10 days')
```

now after i executed this, my result only brings me transaction where the date is ten days before the current date. i'm not getting results for any transactions for the past nine days.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I get all records in the past 10 days.

Answer (score -1):

consider using `between`.

```
select * from transaction
where tdate between CURRENT_DATE  and (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10 DAYS')
```

Comment: You have your arguments in the wrong order. Also, this doesn't answer the question -- ie: what is wrong with the OP's query.

Comment: @MFisherKDX OP wants transactions "date is ten days before the current date". A simple greater-than operators will catch transactions that are in the future, beyond the current date.